# Derivative of differential form

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, frechet-derivative

A smooth differential form $\omega$ on a smooth manifold $M$ is a map $\omega: M \to \bigwedge M$. Since $\bigwedge M$ is a vector bundle, and hence a manifold, if $\omega$ is differentiable as a map $M \to \bigwedge M$ we can form the tangent map $$T\omega: TM \to T\left( \bigwedge M \right).$$ Is a  smooth differential form always differentiable in this sense and is there a relationship to the exterior derivative of the differential form? If not, what is the importance of this derivative?

Comment: $\bigwedge M$ is not a vector space, but a vector bundle.

Comment: @CaptainLama Yeah you're right $\bigwedge_p M$ is a vector space. I'll edit the question.

Comment: This is horrible notation, at the very least. A $p$-form is a section of  the *vector bundle* $\Lambda^p (T^*M)$. Have you tried to write down what you're talking about for the simplest case, say $M=\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Hey, only because you don't use the notation it's not terrible. If we're nitpicking the totally correct way of writing it would be $\cup_{p \in M}\bigwedge (T_p M)^*$. Quite convoluted isn't it? So in math we often use shortcuts :) Your way and my way are both totally reasonable ways of doing that. I also know what a differential form is, that is not the question.

Comment: So, snark aside, what have you gotten when you write this out for a $1$-form on $\Bbb R^2$? And I honestly had no idea what $\bigwedge_p$ was supposed to mean. You can see that you chose $p$ for point, and I chose it for the degree of the form.